# schedule and Callable

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use ScheduledExecutorService inside the main activity, where there are a few user interface controls.  Under some circumstances I wish to delay the method invoked by one of them by a second:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
     Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Callable() {
 public Object call() throws Exception {
  stopSomething();
 }
},
1,
TimeUnit.SECONDS);

try {
 scheduledFuture.get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}

scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
```

Such a snip of code would work in another part of the program, so I know the outline of this solution works at least there.  But in the main activity and in other parts of the program where I've tried (where I could actually use it), Eclipse keeps finding something wrong with this:

ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Callable() {
 public Object call() throws Exception {

If the compile error isn't on `Object call() throws Exception`, it's on `schedule(new Callable()`, like right now.

The red line under schedule is "The method schedule(Runnable, long, TimeUnit) in the type ScheduledExecutorService is not applicable for the arguments (new Callable(){}, int, TimeUnit)"

The red line under Callable is "Callable cannot be resolved to a type"

(Maybe .schedule (Runnable task, long delay, TimeUnit timeunit) is a better method to use here?  If so, what would account for the error "The method schedule(Runnable, long, TimeUnit) in the type ScheduledExecutorService is not applicable for the arguments (new Callable(){}, int, TimeUnit)"?  What does this want?  And how would it be composed?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type for the Callable you are using is Object, but you are not returning anything

```
Callable callable = new Callable() {
 public Object call() throws Exception {
  stopSomething();
  // missing return statement
 };
```

If you don't need to return anything, and don't throw any checked Exception you could use:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
  stopSomething();
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if the thread is old, this answer can be useful for reference.

The signature of the scheduler requires a java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit, but TimeUnit is also the name of other classes, as com.ibm.icu.util.TimeUnit or com.ibm.icu.impl.duration.TimeUnit.

Simply check that you imported the one from the java.util.concurrent package.